# Maven Dynamically Exclude File

Tags: maven

I have a Java project where I need to build 2 versions of the same EAR.

- 1 version needs to include all java files.
- 1 version needs to include all java files, except for one particular java file.

Right now I can achieve this by simply doing a normal Maven build to create the all inclusive EAR.

To build the EAR that excludes that 1 .java file, I just add an exclusion to the maven-compiler-plugin in my POM.xml file.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/AggregatorMessageBean.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

While this approach gives me what I need, it seems like there should be a better way to do this.

For instance, can I pass some kind of argument into Maven that will dictate whether or not that single Java file should be excluded or not?

It would be even better if I was able to build both versions from a single build, but I know I'm probably already pushing Maven beyond it's intended usage.

Has anyone ever had experience with dynamically excluding Java source files from a build?

Comment: An EAR file with source files? Does not make sense?

Comment: Not the source files, but the .java files.

Comment: The java files *are*  the source files?

Comment: @khmarbaise I just want  Maven to build my project without including that one particular file "AggregatorMessageBean.java".

Forget about the terminology of the word "source".

Comment: @khmarbaise My apologies.  I think the title of my question was misleading.  I edited it.

Comment: First terminology is important to exactly understand each other. Apart from that You should make one jar module which only contains the single  `AggegatorMessageBean`and an other one which contains the rest. Than create two separate ear-module. First one which include the one with ÀggregatorMessageBean` and the second ear module which contains the other one. Furhtermore have you configured the compiler-plugin in the EAR module (packaging ear) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Ok, I can try out that approach.  I am using the maven-ear-plugin in the EAR module.